# How do I merge/join lon and lat in my data by matching the country names?

Tags: r, inner-join, merging-data

I am trying to draw a map. I need to merge/join lon and lat data from the ggmap to my data.

My data sets looks like this

dataworld <- read.dta(file ="arrival.dta")

My data sets looks like this:

```
Name Country Date
XXX India 29/01/2016
XXX Brazil 29/02/2016
XXX USA 30/12/2017
.....
XXX India 30/12/2019
```

World map data looks like this;

world_map:

```
lat lon region
XXX XXX Afghanistan
XXX XXX  Armenia
XXX XXX Brazil
XXX USA 
.....
XXX Zimbabwe
```

Observations are different in both the data. I tried leftjoin inner join etc. It fails.

Suggest me how do I join and combine both data by matching the country names.

Comment: Did you try `merge(dataworld, world_map, by.x = 'Country', by.y = 'region')` ?

Comment: ya, I tried. 0 observations created.

Comment: Please update your post with `dput(head(dataworld))` and `dput(head(world_map))`.

Comment: i tried left_jojin but it shows lat and on N/A. btw how do i update my post, quite new here

Comment: i tried dput(head(dataworld)) and dput(head(world_map)) still zero observations created. im quite lost now :(

Comment: `dput` is a way to share data here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 . There is an `edit` button at the end of your post below tags which you can use to edit your post.